# Silverlight: Define event handler in hierarchical data template

Tags: silverlight, treeview, events

I am having problems getting at a click event of a button and am using Silverlight 3.0 w/ matching [Silverlight Toolkit](https://web.archive.org/web/20100316110458/http://www.codeplex.com:80/Silverlight).

## Problem

I have this TreeView:

[TreeView sample http://a.imagehost.org/0939/TreeView.png](http://a.imagehost.org/0939/TreeView.png).

The value for a certain node is the sum of the values of its children. Only in leaves can data be added (for the time being).
What I want to achieve is that a user can add (and eventually remove) entries in the tree to eventually create a custom diagram.
To that end I would like the "plus sign" to insert a new line / node as child of the node where the user clicked. (I.e. if I click the plus at "Display", I get a line below to specify CRT or TFT or whatever.)

Thing is, for all my brain is worth, I don't know how to receive any useful event.
The TextBlock, TextBox and Button are defined in a hierarchical template and I can't define a Click-handler in that template.

OTOH, I haven't found a way to get at the template items of a certain TreeViewItem from within (c#) code. Very well am I able to do trv.ItemContainerGenerator.GetContainerFromItem(item), and as [Justin Angel showed](https://web.archive.org/web/20090628133235/http://silverlight.net:80/blogs/justinangel/archive/2009/05/19/silverlight-treeview-advanced-scenarios-treeviewextended.aspx) I can very well change the font size, but didn't find any way to access the textbox or button.

Is there any way to capture the click event to the button? Or any alternative way of getting something that gives the "add below" functionality?

Thank you in advance.

---

## More Data

The treeview xaml is this:

```
<controls:TreeView x:Name="SankeyDataTree" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SankeyTreeTemplate}" BorderThickness="0" 
    Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <controls:TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
        <controls:TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Loading..."/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
    </controls:TreeViewItem>
</controls:TreeView>
```

I use this HierarchicalDataTemplate (and stole the appraoch from [Timmy Kokke](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128143629/http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/06/29/styling-a-treeview-in-silverlight-and-blend-3.aspx)):

```
<Data:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SankeyTreeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <Grid Height="24">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- ... -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.name, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value.flow, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="4,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding Children, Converter={StaticResource BoxConverter}, ConverterParameter=\{box\}}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.throughput, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="4,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding Children, Converter={StaticResource BoxConverter}, ConverterParameter=\{block\}}"/>
        <Button Margin="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemButtonStyle}">
            <Image Source="../Assets/add.png" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Data:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

To this TreeView is bound a "[SimpleTree](https://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/)", whose Values hold basically onle a string (name) and two doubles (flow and throughput).

```
public String name { get; set; }
public Double flow { get; set; }
public Double throughput { get; set; }
```

(Plus the code for the INotifyPropertyChanged to get a twoway bind to the text boxes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach a `Behavior` to the `Button` in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and let that handle `Click` events from the `Button`.

Download and install the [Expression Blend 3 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=F1AE9A30-4928-411D-970B-E682AB179E17). Add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` in the project and add a `Behavior` attached to a `Button`:

```
public class ButtonClickBehavior : Behavior<Button> {

  protected override void OnAttached() {
    base.OnAttached();
    AssociatedObject.Click += ButtonClick;
  }

  protected override void OnDetaching() {
    base.OnDetaching();
    AssociatedObject.Click -= ButtonClick;
  }

  void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Node node = AssociatedObject.DataContext as Node;
    if (node != null) {
      // Button clicked. Do something to associated node.
    }
  }

}
```

Attach the `Behavior` to the `Button` in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (assuming this namespace declaration: `xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`):

```
<Button Margin="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemButtonStyle}">
  <Image Source="../Assets/add.png" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:ButtonClickBehavior/>
  </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

If desired you can add properties to `ButtonClickBehavior` and set those from XAML to create a more reusable `Behavior`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help!

I knew microsoft would have been thorough and had a way to do what I try to. ;)

Comment: Where is the Node class?  I need this exact behavior in a WPF  UserControl, but can't get it to compile since I don't have a reference to the namespace for the Node class, and I google hasn't helped.  Thanks.

Comment: The `Node` class is you "own" class. It is the class of the object that each node in the tree view is bound to using data binding.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the button click event in the code behind. To get to the data, just bind it to the Tag attribute.

```
<Button Margin="0" Grid.Column="2" 
        Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding}"
        Style="{StaticResource     TreeViewItemButtonStyle}">            
  <Image Source="../Assets/add.png" Margin="0" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>        
</Button>
```

In the code behind, handle it and access the element.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var data = ((Button)sender).Tag as SimpleTreeNode
}
```

Where *SimpleTreeNode* is the name of your tree element class.

You should be able to add a new node to the data found now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)

It confirmed what I suspected; if I have the hierarchical data template in my Page.xaml, it works.
Is there any way to bind an event to the button if the template resides in a resource dictionary (means, in a quite different file)?
(If it was aggregated in the App.xaml via <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries/>, would I have to place the EventHandler in the App.xaml.cs (or appropiate codebehind file)?)